# How to refresh old page when navigated to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

If I navigate to another page and come to the same page again. I need it to be completely refreshed as new page.[image]

If I navigate to dashboard and come back to the same billing page, the values selected in dropdown are there. I need it to be refreshed as a new page without data.

This is code used to navigate page

```
onPress: () {

Get.offAll(() => const FeeStructureViewPage());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way you could do that is by using `then` :

```dart
onPress: () {
  Get.to(() => const FeeStructureViewPage())?.then((value) {
            setState(() {
            });
        });
},
```

This way, when you navigate back the page it will `setState` to rebuild, if rebuilding is the only thing needed to update the state of the UI. In conclusion, the code in `then` will run when you revisit the page.

Comment: do i need to add anything inside the setState?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you need to update some values of the screen before rebulding it, you can do that inside the setState.